# how to put condition on page load or if the button clicked

Tags: jquery

Im new in jquery,on the page load i have some procedure which i put inside :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
     some function....
      });
```

i have a filter button which when i press it i should do the same which its done on the page load,so how can i say,if the button is clicked OR page load,do the same thing?

```
$(document).ready(function() || $("#btn").click(function(){
     some functions.....
 }));
```

is what i want is logical?if so please let me know how to do it

Comment: Any particular reason you changed the accept? The functionality of my second example is identical to Rory's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the logic you want to run to its own function, then call it from both events:

```
$(function() {
  doSomething();

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    doSomething();
  });
});
```

You could also provide the function reference to the handler, depending on the scope you need it to run under:

```
$("#btn").click(doSomething);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just want to click the button on load

```
function yourFunctionName() { .... }

$(function() {
  $("#btn").on("click",yourFunctionName).click()
});
```

or call it in both events

```
function yourFunctionName() { .... }

$(function() {
  yourFunctionName();
  $("#btn").on("click",yourFunctionName);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate this into a `function`:

```
function myEvent(event) {
    //Do something
}
```

Now, you can choose your approach:

#### Normal, simple approach:

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {
    myEvent(event);
    $("#btn").click(myEvent);
});
```

Advantage: easy to implement and read

Disadvantage: Does not cope well with the case when the handler has to be passed to much more places than 2

#### Delegate the handler creation to a function:

```
function myHandlerCreator(events) {
    for (event of events) event(myEvent);
}
```

and call it like:

```
myHandlerCreator([
    $(document).ready,
    $("#btn").click
]);
```

Advantage: Very easy to maintain and elegant to work with, responds well to the case when there are a lot of events to cope with or frequent change to the input

Disadvantage: A new logical layer is created

Comment: I have never seen a usecase for the above. It is certainly not needed for OP's example

Comment: @mplungjan It's certainly good to be able to define handlers for separate events in a simplified, easy-to-read manner. It is not a need to work like this, but an option. It's up to the OP to decide what solution he/she chooses. As about use-cases, imagine having to set the same event handler to at several event types and having to do this in 30 different cases. If you define those separately then you will end up with at least 60, pot possibly 90, 120 such event handler definitions and your code will not be easy to read. Yet you can simplify this.

Comment: Never had that. I would move the event handler to a container and have that test what was clicked

Comment: If I am not mistaken in the example you post, the handleCreator will add the myEvent to document.ready and myEvent to btn.click but not btn.click to document.ready so it would have to run after the btn exists

Comment: @mplungjan if the elements to handle are close to each-other in the tree.

Comment: If not then `document.on("event"`

Comment: @mplungjan yes, you understand it accurately.